Unable to send Message via Graph API even with correct permission set
I am trying to send messages using Graph API where I have certain permissions
email, pages_show_list, business_management, pages_messaging, pages_messaging_subscriptions, instagram_basic, instagram_manage_comments,instagram_manage_insights, instagram_content_publish,, instagram_manage_messages, pages_read_engagement, pages_manage_metadata, pages_read_user_content
Now the wierd part is I have two Roles(Admin both of them, both of them has a Facebook page and connected business instagram account) in the app, Now for one user I am able to send message while in other i get a 403 error
error Data: {
  error: {
    message: '(#200) Please check if access token has enough IG permissions granular scopes for IG to send API, or if IGSID is valid.',
    type: 'OAuthException',
    code: 200,
    error_subcode: 2534067,
    fbtrace_id: 'AouX27HuHoQBu65bb6rBUal'
  }
}
Error Status: 403
Error Headers: AxiosHeaders {
  vary: 'Origin',
  'access-control-allow-origin': '*',
  'cross-origin-resource-policy': 'cross-origin',
  'x-app-usage': '{"call_count":5,"total_cputime":0,"total_time":3}',
  'content-type': 'application/json',
  'www-authenticate': 'OAuth "Facebook Platform" "insufficient_scope" "(#200) Please check if access token has enough IG permissions granular scopes for IG to send API, or if IGSID is valid."',
  'facebook-api-version': 'v19.0',
  'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=15552000; preload',
  pragma: 'no-cache',
  'cache-control': 'no-store',
  expires: 'Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT',
  'x-fb-request-id': 'AouX27HuHoQBu65bb6rBUal',
  'x-fb-trace-id': 'ERIKbq1Rjf7',
  'x-fb-rev': '1012935256',
  'x-fb-debug': 'mVMrRrBF3H+nrrHR45BNeWtyqALnup35FrQb9RD8JNQCpmH3n8NhTPYqWVns6Snt1oY6x7RCHIvGzO1cJLP9UQ==',
  date: 'Sat, 20 Apr 2024 18:38:20 GMT',
  'proxy-status': 'http_request_error;  
......... <some other headers>
'x-fb-connection-quality': 'EXCELLENT; q=0.9, rtt=5, rtx=0, c=10, mss=1380, tbw=372, tp=-1, tpl=-1, uplat=514, ullat=0',
  'alt-svc': 'h3=":443"; ma=86400',
  connection: 'close',
  'content-length': '241'
}

Can anyone please tell me what is going wrong. I tried to create another app, and didn't add user1(for which messages were working) added only user2 and tried sending messages, it was not working. But as soon as I added user1 to this new app, again i was able to send message through this User1's page access token.
Expecting it to work. but it didn't

got any solution?

Yeah, figured out that I was utilizing the wrong Instagram ID instead of using IG-SID.

do you have SDK library for use it ?

@VladimirB No, I implemented it on my own in NodeJS. If you are stuck on something, do let me know, I can try helping out.

Thanks @RajneeshSharma just looking for ready same with Instagram DM - incoming and response
